# Linearity in Expected Value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have 4 cards, number 1, 2, 3, and 4.

I draw 2 cards at random and without replacement. What is the expected value of the sum?

Solution:
$E[X_1+X_2]=E[X_1]+E[X_2],$  where $E[X_i]= 1/4(1+2+3+4)=2.5$. Thus $E[X_1+X_2]=2*2.5 =5.$

I totally understand that regardless $X_1,X_2$ are dependent or independent, linearity in expectation holds.

My question is, how come after taking the expectation, you can treat $E[X_1]=E[X_2]=E[X_i]?$

---

This has sharp contrast with the Coupon Collection problems, in which the problem asks the expected number of attempts in order to collect at least 1 coupon of each N type. Linearity of expectation still holds. 
The solution is:

$E[Coupon_1 + Coupon_2 + .. + Coupon_N] = E[Coupon_1] + ... + E[Coupon_N]$

however, $E[Coupon_1] \neq E[Coupon_2]\neq E[Coupon_3].....$.

Whereas in the former problem, you can treat $E[X_i]$ to be the same, while in both cases, they are all dependent on the other random variables. But in the later case, the $E[X_i]$ are no longer the same.  I am confused!

Comment: Maybe use total law of probability in the expected value of $X_2.$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Long story short:** The random variables have identical expectations when they follow *identical distributions*.

---

I have a deck of these four cards, with values 1,2,3,4.   I shuffle the deck and place two cards face down, one on your left and one on your right.

What is your expectation for the value of the card on your left?

What is your expectation for the value of the card on your right?

---

*Hint:* I have not told you which I placed down first.   Does it matter?

Indeed, let us go ahead an place the other two cards face down.   What is your expectation for the values of each of these as well?

---

You see, the dependency of the cards does means that the *conditional expectation*, $\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1)$ will indeed not be constant but rather a function of $X_1$; however we are *not discussing* the conditional expectations, just the expectation.

Still, let us examine the conditional expectation and use the law of iterated expectation:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1=k) ~&=~\begin{cases} \tfrac 13(~~~~~~~2+3+4)&:&k=1\\\tfrac 13(1+~~~~~~~3+4)&:&k=2\\\tfrac 13(1+2+~~~~~~~4)&:&k=2\\\tfrac 13(1+2+3~~~~~~~)&:&k=4 \end{cases}\\[2ex] \mathsf E(X_2) ~&=~ \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1)) \\[1ex] &=~ \tfrac 14\big(\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1=1)+\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1=2)+\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1=3)+\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1=4)\big)\\[1ex] &=~ \tfrac 14(1+2+3+4) \\[1ex] &=~ \mathsf E(X_1)\end{align}$$

---

**Contrast with Coupon Collection.  Why is it not the same?**

Where as the random variables for the cards are the values of the cards drawn, the random variables used in the coupon collection are: the count of draws (with replacement) after the $k-1$-th new value until the $k$ new value is draw ("new value" meaning a value not previously drawn).

That is, with the same deck of cards, let $Y_1$ be the count of draws until the first new value is drawn, $Y_2$ be the count of draws *after* that until the second new value is drawn, $Y_3$ be the count of draws *after* that until the third new value is drawn, and $Y_4$ be the count of draws *after* that until the last new value is drawn.

$$\mathsf E(Y_1)=1, \mathsf E(Y_2)=4/3, \mathsf E(Y_3)=4/2, \mathsf E(Y_4)=4$$

These *random variables* have different expectations *not* because they are dependent or independent,† but rather *it is* because the random variables have *different distributions*.‡

(† They are in fact *independent*.)

(‡ They follow Geometric Distributions with *different rates*.)

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that in $\mathsf E(X_2) = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1)) = \mathsf E(X_1)$, the first equality is always true, while the latter equality so happens due to the uniform probabilities. For example, if we assigned unequal probabilities of $0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.997$ to outcomes $1, 2, 3, 4$, then $\mathsf E(X_1) \approx 4$ and $\mathsf E(X_2) \approx 2$. With respect to the hint about assigning expectations to left and right cards not knowing which is placed first, that would be $\approx 3$ for each here, and does change again if you ask about all four (to 2.5).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that $X_i$ are copies of one and the same random variable, namely, the random variable that returns the number on a card randomly drawn from your card collection.

Comment: But then clearly, if you have a 2nd draw, since without replacement, the 2nd draw is different from the 1st draw. I am wondering how come you can treat $E[X_2] = E[X_1]$

Comment: @wrek I disagree. It is the replacement that actually allows to treat them as identical, as if the whole set of card is shuffled, resetted, and a new draw is made. Also, when I say "identical", I mean that their probability distribution is identical.

Answer (score 2):

$X_1$ and $X_2$ follow the same discrete uniform distribution (since $X_1$ and $X_2|X_1$ are uniform, so is $X_2$). Hence they have identical expectations.

Answer (score 0):

$$Pr(x_2 = 1) = Pr(x_1 = 1)*0 + Pr(x_1 \neq1) * Pr(x_2 = 1| x_1 \neq 1) = 0 + \frac{1}{3} * \frac{3}{4} = \frac {1}{4}$$

Similarly, we have

$$Pr(x_2 = i) = \frac {1}{4}, \quad i = 1,2,3,4$$.

Proceeding forward (i.e., regarding $X_2$ as $X_1$), we can derive

$$Pr(x_3 = i) = \frac {1}{4}, \quad i = 1,2,3,4$$

and

$$Pr(x_4 = i) = \frac {1}{4}, \quad i = 1,2,3,4$$